# jquery click not working on dynamically added hrefs in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Hello I have some links in my HTML code. I want to change the href property of each link on hover and then on clicking this link I want to open it up in a new tab. The code is as follows:

```
$('.identifierClass').hover(function(e) {
if(condition) // is true
{
    $(element).attr("href", "url/goes/here").off().click(function(e) {
        $(element).attr("target", "_blank");
    });
 }
});
```

Everything is working properly in Chrome/Firefox, however, on clicking the link in IE 11 it simply hangs and click wont work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If they are dynamic, please use this `.on('click', '#' + $(element).attr("id"), function(e) { instead of `.click(function(e) {`

Comment: Can you please post the code where the hover event in binded.

Comment: @erkaner I tried your adding your code but in vain

Comment: I posted an answer below about correctly binding dynamic elements.  However, I don't understand the href part of your code, are you just trying to replace the href after click?

Comment: @Jason hi thanks for your time. There are basically several objects on my page. So for example. there are x Students, each student has properties - class, ranks, etc. When I hover over Student1 a popup shows links "class" and "rankings".So this popup's links get a new href value when hovering over different Student objects. So when Im over Student1 the popup link for class could be "url/class/student1" and for rankings it will be "url/rankings/student1". And so the hrefs change when hovering over different Student objects.
 I hope this helps

Comment: Ok, so yes, see my answer below, i think it contains all the components you need to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to a static or preexisting element that the dynamic elements will be created inside of:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.identifierClass',function(e) {
if(condition) // is true
{
    $(element).attr("href", "url/goes/here").attr("target", "_blank");
 }
});
```

Edit: here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/rftnh2Lg/4/) of it and I also had to use 'mouseenter' instead of 'hover' when using the string name for the event. [jquery .hover() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

In the fiddle i show you two divs being added dynamically:

```
$('#place').html('<div class="identifierClass">hover1</div><div class="identifierClass2">hover2</div>');
```

Above that, I set my event handlers, for hover1 div, I set the event on the document using a specified selector:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.identifierClass',function(e) {
alert('hi');
});
```

You can see this works when you hover of 'hover1' text on the right and, conversely, you can see hover2 doesn't work using this binding:

```
$('.identifierClass2').hover(function(e) {
alert('hi2');
});
```

[here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is a link to the jquery documentation on event delegation.

Edit2: I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/rftnh2Lg/9/) to address the 'href' manipulation.  It appears that you just want to change some attributes on the hover portion:

I modified the 'mouseenter' binding to look like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.identifierClass',function(e) {
    alert('hi');    $('#someLink').attr('href','http://www.bing.com').attr('target','_blank');
});
```

I don't think you need the 'off' or the 'click', but that is based off of some assumptions, so please feel free to comment and I can update accordingly.  This, though, will change the href when the mouseenters the dynamic element and change the target attribute as well.